# How to compile only the KVM kernel module from Linux source tree?

Tags: linux, compile, kernel-module

I am hoping to compile the KVM module from Linux source code and install it on my Debian machine. However, I do not want to compile the entire Linux. My kernel comes from Debian.

I heard from the Internet that `make M=arch/x86/kvm` may work, so I decided to try it.

My `uname -r` is `5.10.0-14-amd64`. The commands I am running are basically

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source-5.10
tar xaf /usr/src/linux-source-5.10.tar.xz 
cd linux-source-5.10/
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make M=arch/x86/kvm
```

However, when running `make M=arch/x86/kvm`, I see the error

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/kvm/../../../virt/kvm/kvm_main.o', needed by 'arch/x86/kvm/kvm.o'.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1846: arch/x86/kvm] Error 2
```

This is because the `virt/kvm` directory is not built. However, I tried the following, but none of them work

```
make M=virt
make M=virt/kvm
(cd virt; make -C .. M=.)
(cd virt/kvm; make -C ../.. M=.)
(cd arch/x86/kvm; make -C ../../.. M=.)
(cd arch/x86/kvm; make -C ../../.. M=. modules)
(cd arch/x86/kvm; make -C ../../.. M=. kvm.ko)
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Compile_kernel_module says that I need to run `modules_prepare`. Using the following commands, I am able to compile a `kvm.ko` ELF file.

```
make SUBLEVEL=0 EXTRAVERSION=-14-amd64 modules_prepare
make M=arch/x86/kvm
ls arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko
```

However, I cannot install it using `insmod` or `modprobe`. `modprobe`'s `--force-vermagic` option also does not work. The version looks correct, though.

```
$ sudo insmod arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko: Invalid module format
$ strings /usr/lib/modules/5.10.0-14-amd64/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko | grep 5.10.
5.10.0-14-amd64
vermagic=5.10.0-14-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
$ strings arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko | grep 5.10.
5.10.0-14-amd64
vermagic=5.10.0-14-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
$
```

How should I build and install the KVM module?

Note: This question is originally posted from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72419524/how-to-compile-only-the-kvm-kernel-module-from-linux-source-tree)

Comment: I just had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72495863/is-it-possible-to-build-linuxs-kvm-as-a-module would you mind joining forces? What do you want to do?

Comment: @Guerlando OCs For me, the workaround is to complete Linux from scratch (takes ~1 hour, which is what I want to solve in this question). After that, following https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Compile_kernel_module will succeed on Debian. I am working on x86 platform, where CONFIG_KVM is a tristate ( https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18/source/arch/x86/kvm/Kconfig#L21 ). But I guess you are working on ARM, where CONFIG_KVM is a boolean ( https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18/source/arch/arm64/kvm/Kconfig#L21 ). We may be facing different problems.